# What's the difference in calling ThinkingSphinx.search and ModelName.search...?

Tags: ruby, thinking-sphinx

I have started using ThinkingSphinx for text search but can anybody explain me what's the difference between these two way of calling thinkingsphinx search , though I see both returns the same result and working fine in my local system. But does it effect in some other environment like production.??

Answer (score 2):

[From the documentation of Thinking Sphinx](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/searching.html#global):

> You can use all the same syntax to search across all indexed models in
>   your application:
>
> ```
> ThinkingSphinx.search 'pancakes'
> ```

So if you call `search` on `ThinkingSphinx`, it searches in all of your indexed models.

Comment: Mario's got it right - but of course, if you've only got indices on a single model, there's no difference.